# Whole word search in less?

Tags: command-line, iterm

How can I do a whole word search in `less`? Per [this post](https://www.unix.com/302298514-post2.html?s=13c8f40a74726d31a53ec2333700c15f) on a unix/linux forum you can use regex 'whole word' markers `\<word\>` but that doesn't seem to work for me on macOS 10.13.4 (17E202) in iTerm2 on less version 487 (found by `less --version`).

Comment: The solution you cite works fine for less when compiled to use GNU regexs.

Comment: The URL isn't accessible at the time and [the domain has been excluded from Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://www.unix.com/302298514-post2.html?s=13c8f40a74726d31a53ec2333700c15f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `less --version` gives

```
less 487 (POSIX regular expressions)
```

so you need to use POSIX regexps in `less`. To learn more about them you can read through `re_format(7)` to find

```
There are two special cases= of bracket expressions: the bracket expressions `[[:<:]]'
and `[[:>:]]' match the null string at the beginning and end of a word respectively.
```

So to search for `word` you need to enter `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]` on the search prompt (which probably isn't very useful in most situations).

PS: This also applies to the version of `less` installed via Homebrew. You *might* have more luck by compiling it yourself and specifying an alternative regexp library (or by modifying the source accordingly).

Comment: Running `less --version` is the key! On my Ubuntu system, less is built by default with GNU regex support, and so the original solution mentioned in the question works fine (and is easy to type!).

Comment: I get with `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]` `invalid pattern` on `less 551`, am on `ubuntu`.